# How to use CUDA 6.0 with XCODE 5

Tags: c, xcode, cuda, xcode5, nvcc

My question may completely be a noob. Sorry, for that but I have been trying to compile my first Cuda code in Xcode and I'm lost where and how I could set up the IDE to invoke NVCC.
I installed the latest CUDA toolkit CUDA 6.0 and have even installed GCC 4.8 using brew. I have XCODE 5.5
When I run my code from XCODE all the directives like **global** are marked as unidentified.
I don't where and to change the settings to invoke NVCC. I will be really thankful, if anyone could help me with this.

Further, when I created the XCODE project, I created it as a C project. So, I placed the CUDA code in this C file, which is what is giving me the above mentioned errors. I tried to replace this .C file with a .cu file (just change the extension), which too failed badly - XCODE didn't even know what to do with the .cu files

COuld anyone please help me?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you follow the directions in the [mac getting started document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html#axzz30OYGDA9g)?

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact, I'm able to compile and run the programs mentioned in the document successfully. For Querydevice and bandwidthtest, I'm having PASS results. But I don't know how to use Xcode to write and run the programs...!

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm facing the same problems now

Comment: No... I believe Xcode is not compatible with NSIGHT. Apple is only promoting the use of OpenCL.

Answer (score 1):

I have given it a try. Although I have not completely succeeded I thought I'd post my progress here in hopes of helping others. The steps I took were inspired by [this page](https://clang-omp.github.io).

1. Create a new Xcode project
2. Under Build Settings add a new user defined setting CC with the value `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc`.
3. Add `/usr/local/cuda/include` to `Header Search Paths` under Build Settings.
4. Set `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` to `No`.
5. Add `/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib` to `Link Binary With Libraries` under `Build Phases`.

For any `C` files you create set their extension to `.cu` in the File Inspector, after you have done that you have to set the type of that file to `C source` to get syntax highlighting, by going to Editor->Syntax Coloring->C.

Problems with this setup:
 - Xcode can't run the executable, at least nog if it is compiled for debugging. However you can make it copy the executable to some reasonable location and run it in the terminal.
- Whenever you try 'Build for running' sometimes Xcode magically destroys the whole project.

Comment: How do you set the type of the file to C source?

Comment: @JudeMichaelMurphy I've expanded my answer to answer your question. However I wrote this quite a while ago and haven't touched the combination Xcode and Cuda since. But I think that this is what I meant then.